Instruments stopped working after MacOS Sonoma 14.5 update
I'm developing a C++ application and was using instruments for profiling and was very satisfied with it. However, after updating my OS to Sonoma 14.5, the instruments still works, but throws SIGABRT after 1ms, during dyld package loading phase.
Here is a screenshot:

I also tried upgrading XCode 15.4, then 16.0 Beta1 and finally 16.0 Beta2 to no avail.

If you add the “stdout/stderr” instrument to your file and record again, do you see any logging there? That might help explain what’s gone wrong.

It breaks out during the first allocation ever made by the system, which happens even before the logging.

Have you tried updating Xcode?

yes, to no avail.
